# Передача сигналов из гостя хосту

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

Есть гостевая система линуксовая. Как при нажатии, например, на `ctrl+L` передать сигнал на хост на винде, чтобы блокировка экрана произошла на хосте?

Надо чтобы блокировка была именно на уровне хоста, чтобы нельзя было получить доступ к компьютеру просто свернув виртуалку.

Comment: знаю как сделать если хост на линухе)

Comment: какой язык програмирования?

Comment: @eri надо наоборот, но можете рассказать, мб нагуглить проще будет

Comment: @root_of_the_live если есть программное решение, то любой. Но я подразумевал настройку ОС/Virtualbox-а

Comment: За что минусы вопросу?

Comment: сомневаюсь что такая настройка существует.

Answer (score 0):

В сессии пользователя на гостевой системе нужно написать программу.

Подключаешься к dbus и ждешь сигнал org.gnome.ScreenSaver.ActiveChanged или org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.ActiveChanged

Или системный сервис который слушет систеный service org.freedesktop.login1, path /org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto, interface org.freedesktop.login1.Session, signal Lock (но он пока не готов)

Дальше отправляешь текст в COM порт что сессия залоченна.

На хост системе подключаешься к виртуальному COM порту (хост-канал в идеале, но проще по TCP) и ждешь этого слова. По нему выполняешь блокировку экрана запустив команду.

Для простоты реализации гостевого агента можно отправить вывод `dbus-monitor` в ком порт.

```
dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Session',member='Lock'"\
  > /dev/ttyS1
```

Но на хосте всеравно прийдется программировать, чтоб распарсить сигнал.

Comment: если без средств программирования (я имею в виду использование доступных средств администрирования), то можно настроить реагирование на события аудита возникновения сетевых соединений между гостевой и хостовой машиной: при наличии существующих настроенных сетевых интерфейсов. Либо на события аудита операций с файловыми объектами в общих папках: при подключении сервиса [Shared Folders](https://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/virtualbox-share-folder-host-guest/).